# How can i only use Visual Graph Tab to visualize my Ontology without user can access my respository?

Tags: graphdb

I have create my web that can visualize RDF, so i use GraphDB Visualization to my RDF. But i want user can only access the visualization Tab in GraphDB without access my respository. How can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the embedded parameter that hides all GDB specific menus and then put the visual graph in an iframe in your application.

Add `embedded = true` to your visual graph URL.